# C++- Duplicate data in datagridview

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, c++-cli

I try to make winform to add data to database but the dat duplicated in datagridview but in the database it's not duplicated
I try data to several tables at once is there any other ways to solve?
I would like to display data in my datagridview without duplicates. I don't know how did it duplicated.
searched Stack Overflow for this kind of problem. But I found several similar problems regarding this one, but No solutions in C++
[image]
[image: duplicated data]

```
private: System::Void btnRefresh_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    MySqlConnection^ conn = gcnew MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    conn->Open();
    String ^ cmdString = "SELECT DISTINCT* from booking,customer,menu,menu_items,request,stuff,stuff_take_request,tables  ";
    MySqlCommand^ cmd2 = gcnew MySqlCommand(cmdString, conn);
    MySqlDataAdapter^ cmd = gcnew MySqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
    dataGridView1->ClearSelection();
    DataTable^ dt = gcnew DataTable();
    cmd->Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1->DataSource = dt;
    conn->Close();

}
private: System::Void txtserach_KeyPress(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e) {
    try {
        if (e->KeyChar == (Char)13)
        {
            DataView^ dv = sqlDt->DefaultView;
            dv->RowFilter = String::Format("FirstName like '%{0}%'", txtserach->Text);
            dataGridView1->DataSource = dv->ToTable();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception^ ex)
    {
        MessageBox::Show(ex->Message, "Data Entery Form", MessageBoxButtons::YesNo, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
    }
}
private: System::Void btnSearch_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    try {


        String^ Search = txtserach->Text;
        sqlConn->ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=N123;database=restaurant2";
        sqlCmd->Connection = sqlConn;
        DataTable^ adapter = gcnew DataTable();
        sqlDtA->Fill(sqlDt);
        dataGridView1->DataSource = sqlDt;

    }
    catch (Exception^ ex)
    {
        MessageBox::Show(ex->Message, "Data Entery Form", MessageBoxButtons::YesNo, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
    }
}
private: System::Void AddNew_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    String^ ID = txtID->Text;
    String^ FirstName = txtFirst->Text;
    String^ LastName = txtLast->Text;
    String^ Phone = txtmobile->Text;
    String^ ID_Booking = txtID_B->Text;
    
    String^ ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=N123;database=restaurant2";

    MySqlConnection^ conn = gcnew MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    
    String^ Data = datam->Text;

    String^ cmdString2 = "INSERT INTO restaurant2.Booking(ID,Date) VALUES(@ID2,@Date)";
    MySqlCommand^ cmd = gcnew MySqlCommand(cmdString2, conn);

    cmd->Parameters->AddWithValue("@ID2", ID);
    cmd->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Date", Data);


    String^ cmdString = "INSERT INTO restaurant2.Customer(ID,Fname,Lname,Phone,ID_Booking) VALUES(@ID,@Fname,@Lname,@Phone,@ID_Booking)";
    MySqlCommand^ cmd2= gcnew MySqlCommand(cmdString, conn);

    cmd2->Parameters->AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
    cmd2->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Fname", FirstName);
    cmd2->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Lname", LastName);
    cmd2->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Phone", Phone);
    cmd2->Parameters->AddWithValue("@ID_Booking", ID);






    String^ Name = cboMenu->Text;
    String^ cmdString3 = "INSERT INTO restaurant2.Menu(ID,Name) VALUES(@ID3,@Name)";
    MySqlCommand^ cmd3 = gcnew MySqlCommand(cmdString3, conn);

    cmd3->Parameters->AddWithValue("@ID3", ID);
    cmd3->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Name", Name);



    String^ Item_name = txtItem->Text;
    String^ Quantity = txtQ->Text;
    String^ Price = txtPrice->Text;

    String^ cmdString4 = "INSERT INTO restaurant2.menu_items(ID, Item_name, Prices, Quantity, ID_Menu) VALUES(@ID4,@Item_name,@Prices,@Quantity,@ID_Menu)";
    MySqlCommand^ cmd4 = gcnew MySqlCommand(cmdString4, conn);

    cmd4->Parameters->AddWithValue("@ID4", ID);
    cmd4->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Item_name", Item_name);
    cmd4->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Prices", Price);
    cmd4->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Quantity", Quantity);
    cmd4->Parameters->AddWithValue("@ID_Menu", ID);

    String^ Time = txtTime->Text;

    String^ cmdString5 = "INSERT INTO restaurant2.Request(ID, Time, ID_Table) VALUES(@ID5,@Time,@ID_Table)";
    MySqlCommand^ cmd5 = gcnew MySqlCommand(cmdString5, conn);

    cmd5->Parameters->AddWithValue("@ID5", ID);
    cmd5->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Time", Time);
    cmd5->Parameters->AddWithValue("@ID_Table", ID);


    String^ cmdString6 = "INSERT INTO restaurant2.request_menu_items(ID_Request, Menu_items_id) VALUES(@ID_Request,@Menu_items_id)";
    MySqlCommand^ cmd6 = gcnew MySqlCommand(cmdString6, conn);

    cmd6->Parameters->AddWithValue("@ID_Request", ID);
    cmd6->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Menu_items_id", ID);


    String^ Fname = txtSFname->Text;
    String^ Lname = txtLname->Text;
    String^ Role = txtRole->Text;
    String^ Stuff = txtStuff->Text;

    String^ cmdString7 = "INSERT INTO restaurant2.stuff(ID, Fname, Lname, Roles) VALUES(@ID7, @Fname2, @Lname2, @Roles)";
    MySqlCommand^ cmd7 = gcnew MySqlCommand(cmdString7, conn);

    cmd7->Parameters->AddWithValue("@ID7", Stuff);
    cmd7->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Fname2", Fname);
    cmd7->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Lname2", Lname);
    cmd7->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Roles", Role);




    String^ cmdString8 = "INSERT INTO restaurant2.stuff_take_request(ID_Request, Stuff_id) VALUES(@ID_Request2, @Stuff_id)";
    MySqlCommand^ cmd8 = gcnew MySqlCommand(cmdString8, conn);

    cmd8->Parameters->AddWithValue("@ID_Request2", ID);
    cmd8->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Stuff_id", Stuff);

    String^ Type = cboMember->Text;
    String^ No_OF = TxtNO->Text;
    String^ cmdString9 = "INSERT INTO restaurant2.tables(ID, Type, Num_of_people, ID_Booking) VALUES(@ID78, @Type, @Num_of_people, @ID_Booking89)";
    MySqlCommand^ cmd9 = gcnew MySqlCommand(cmdString9, conn);

    cmd9->Parameters->AddWithValue("@ID78", ID);
    cmd9->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Type", Type);
    cmd9->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Num_of_people", No_OF);
    cmd9->Parameters->AddWithValue("@ID_Booking89", ID);

    cmd->ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd2->ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd3->ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd4->ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd9->ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd5->ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd6->ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd7->ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd8->ExecuteNonQuery();


    try {

    }

        

    catch (Exception^ e)
    {
        MessageBox::Show("incorrect DATA");
    }
    conn->Close();
}


private: System::Void cboMenu_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
}
private: System::Void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewCellEventArgs^ e) {
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the following code to remove duplicate data

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    dataGridView1->DataSource = 0;
    String^ connstr = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
    SqlConnection^ connection = gcnew SqlConnection(connstr);
    connection->Open();
    String^ sql = "Select * from QWE";
    //SqlCommand^ command = gcnew SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    SqlDataAdapter^ adapter = gcnew SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
    DataTable^ table = gcnew DataTable();
    adapter->Fill(table);
    DataTable ^distinctTable = table->DefaultView->ToTable( /*distinct*/ true);
    
    dataGridView1->DataSource = distinctTable;

    connection->Close();
}
```

Here is result:

[image]

[image]